# A question related to normality of subring of a normal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Suppose $R$ and $S$ are integral domains such that $R \subset S$. Suppose there exists a map (ring homomorphism) $\phi:S\rightarrow R$ such that $\phi$ is the identity on $R$.

I am trying to show that if $S$ is normal, then $R$ is normal as well, but I am struggling to see why this is the case.

Any hint/help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** An integral domain is *normal* if it is its own integral closure in its field of fractions.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a map $\phi:S\to S$ that is identity on $R$?

Comment: I meant to say $\phi:S\rightarrow R$ that is the identity on $R$. Just edited the question to reflect the change.

Comment: By map do you mean ring homomorphism or morphism of $R$-modules or just a set map?

Comment: It is a ring map/homomorphism.

Comment: @neophyte I forgot to tell you that many properties are descending from S to R in this frame. For instance, UFD and GCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Q(R)\subseteq Q(S)$, and $S$ is integrally closed, an element $a\in Q(R)$ which is integral over $R$ belongs to $S$.

Let $p\in R[X]$ be a monic polynomial of minimal degree such that $p(a)=0$. Then $\phi(p(a))=p(\phi(a))=0$. We can write $p(X)=(X-\phi(a))q(X)$ with $q\in R[X]$ monic. From $p(a)=0$ we get $a=\phi(a)\in R$ or $q(a)=0$. But the later contradicts the minimality of $\deg p$.